# redirecting output to a file in C

Tags: linux, shell

i coded a basic shell in C for executing basic commands it'll execute commands `ls`, `ls -al` , `ls -al | more` etc.

i want to execute following command in my shell.
like ;

```
ls -al > a.txt
```

this will give me `a.txt` file which contain output of `ls -al` process.
i found a one solution, it's changing the command in my shell like `[command1] | tee [filename]`. in this instance it'll change `ls -al > a.txt` to `ls -al | tee a.txt`. but this process gives the output to file and terminal as well. how to stop printing output in terminal.

or are there are any better solution rather than using tee command.
thanks in advance...

Comment: why `|` output redirection symbol works in your shell, and `>` don't ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the result of my testing things out with dup2

The more subtle point is remembering fflush at the right times :) Otherwise, you'll get very surprising results.

Also, prefer `fileno` instead of hardcoding `1` (stdout) `2` (stderr).

Redirecting `stdin` was left as an exercise for the reader

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int out = open("cout.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0600);
    if (-1 == out) { perror("opening cout.log"); return 255; }

    int err = open("cerr.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0600);
    if (-1 == err) { perror("opening cerr.log"); return 255; }

    int save_out = dup(fileno(stdout));
    int save_err = dup(fileno(stderr));

    if (-1 == dup2(out, fileno(stdout))) { perror("cannot redirect stdout"); return 255; }
    if (-1 == dup2(err, fileno(stderr))) { perror("cannot redirect stderr"); return 255; }

    puts("doing an ls or something now");

    fflush(stdout); close(out);
    fflush(stderr); close(err);

    dup2(save_out, fileno(stdout));
    dup2(save_err, fileno(stderr));

    close(save_out);
    close(save_err);

    puts("back to normal output");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one thing, shell overwrites the data into the file if file was there otherwise it'll create, then how to overwrite it

Comment: @Zeemaan: using `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` should work (or `creat("cout.log", 0600)` instead of open). See [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/open.html) and [creat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/creat.html)

Comment: fflush(stdout); do print the stuffs what inside the file as well, means output replicated to stdout as well.. is it important to use fflush?

Comment: @Zeemaan: I suspect you're doing it in the wrong order then. You need to flush before reassigning output streams, as in my answer. And yes I strongly recommmend doing the `fflush` (usually streams are line-buffered, so if you only write full lines, e.g. with `puts` there wouldn't be much difference. But that is a big 'if')

Comment: This is nice :). But what if I want to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same log file ???

Comment: @aditya Just do the same: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a35a6a2df392ef9 If you require intermixing output and line-buffering is not enough, consider using GNU `stdbuf` or `setvbuf` API calls to make streams unbuffering

Answer (score 5):

Don't use pipe when the output is to go to a file.

When you fork the child to run the `ls` command, you note the redirection, and open the file; you then use `dup2()` (or `close()` and `dup()`) so that the file descriptor is now standard output for the child; you close the duplicated file descriptor - the one returned by `open()`; then you execute `ls` as usual; its standard output is now sent to the file.

Note that you do the non-pipe I/O redirection after forking, not before.  Pipes have to be set up before forking, but other I/O redirection does not.

Answer (score 2):

Before you call `execve(2)` in the newly created process to execute the command, you can redirect its standard input or output via the [`dup2(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) system call:

```
/* redirect stdout to a file */
dup2(1, some_open_file_descriptor);
```

Of course, you need to have some error handling.