# redirecting output of sed (piped from grep) to a file in C program

Tags: c, sed, pipe

I am using the following command to redirect the output of sed to a tmp file:

```
grep --include=*.txt -A 3 -rnw abx/ -F -e 'simple' | sed -n 's#.*/\([^/]*\.txt\).*"\([^"]*\)*"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/\*[[:space:]]*col[[:space:]]*\*/#\1\n\2#p' > tmp
```

The output is redirected in tmp if it is used in a terminal but in C program, nothing is written to 'tmp'.

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()  {
  char cmd[1028];

   strcpy (cmd, "grep --include=*.txt -A 3 -rnw abx/ -F -e 'simple' | sed -u -n 's#.*/\\([^/]*\\.txt\\).*\"\\([^\"]*\\)*\"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/\\*[[:space:]]*col[[:space:]]*\\*/#\\1\\n\\2#p' > tmp");

  system (cmd);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Example text file:

```
simple =
"sik", /* fill */
"trauma", /* type */
"hui", /* col */
```

This file is stored in abx/.

Comment: you could print the string to see what you are doing. You can also check the return value of the system call.

Comment: system call return value is 0. I have edited the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirecting output to a file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516823/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: @Cyrus Just tested that solution but no luck. cerr.log and cout.log are both empty after program execution.

Comment: sed can write to a file itself with command `w`.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing wrong with that monstrous regular expression? It seems to be working fine, if I remove it.

Comment: @Shahzad: or remove output redirection and append this to your pipe: `| dd of="tmp"`

Comment: @Cyrus No luck dd ain't working too.

Comment: Try using an absolute pathnane instead of `tmp`.

Comment: @Cyrus Though dd works fine on command line.

Comment: @Cyrus Changing to absolute path is not working also. 
`Output:`
`0+0 records in`
`0+0 records out`
`0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.0544728 s, 0.0 kB/s`

Comment: Show an example input file.

Comment: @n.m. I have posted an example file.

Comment: Have you tested this file with the script you have posted? It outputs nothing. Unless you have manipulated your environment somehow so that `grep` and `sed` do not treat newline characters specially, there's no reason for it to output anything. If you remove the newline characters from your input file, then both the command line and the C code output the same thing `moo.txt\nhui`. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @n.m. Please check the script now with the input.

Comment: Still works in both command line and compiled versions.

Comment: It would be great if you eliminated irrelevant details. Does this problem have anything to do with redirection? Remove redirection and check if it still reproduces. Grep? Remove it and check. Monstrous regex? Replace with a trivial one and check. You may find out that you want to ask an entirely different question (if at all).

Comment: @n.m. You are right. Even a simple `grep hui def.txt > out.txt` is having an unexpected behavior. I think there is some serious issue with my Debian system.

Comment: @n.m. `grep hui def.txt > out.txt` has return value of `0` at the command line while in C, it has `1045977456`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to "double escape" the "\" in your regular expression.

```
([^/]*\\.txt\\) --> ([^/*\\\\.txt\\\\)
```

As C will change a "\ \" to a "\" when it builds the string and I think cmd will also change "\ \" to "\".