# Redirecting STDOUT to text file doesn't work properly

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

The parent process executes hello.exe (which prints "Hello!\n" to stdout) after having its stdout changed to W-pipeside.

The child process accepts this (stdin changed to R-pipeside) and redirects output to the out.txt file. I have followed the guidelines and many similar problems on here and don't see anything wrong with the code.

The problem is that the out.txt file gets created, but it's empty. Nothing gets written.

```
int main (void)
{
    pid_t child;
    int Pipe[2];

    (void) pipe(Pipe);

    child = fork();

    if (child == 0)
    {
        //Redirecting Child's STDIN to Pipe's read.
        (void) close(0);
        (void) dup(Pipe[0]);
        (void) close(Pipe[0]);
        (void) close(Pipe[1]);

        //Redirecting Child's STDOUT to out.txt file.
        int file = open("out.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        (void) close(1);
        (void) dup(file);
        (void) close(file);
    }   
    else 
    { 
        //parent process
        (void) close(1);
        (void) dup(Pipe[1]);
        (void) close(Pipe[0]);
        (void) close(Pipe[1]);
        (void) execl("hello.exe", "hello.exe", (char*)NULL);
        perror("execl");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicating stdin and stdout is not enough. You need to actually read from and write to them respectively in the child process.

Comment: pipes are for directing data from one process to another, not from a process to a file. If you want hello.exe's output to go to out.txt, you don't need pipes, just close(1) then open("out.txt",...) and execl("hello.exe",...), no need to pipe() or fork()

Comment: The child process opens a file, then closes it. If you want something written in between, you have to write it.

Comment: When you include `O_CREAT` in the flags, `open()` takes 3 arguments: the third is the permissions for the file, which will be modified by `umask`.  None of your code in the child reads from standard input; none of your code in the child writes to standard output.  The file is only created and never modified.

Comment: @kaylum Can you please provide more information on how to correctly read and write in the child process? Does that mean the pipe for stdin in the child process isn't correct, too? I've surfed through many similar solutions here on StackOverflow that were telling me that duplicating is indeed sufficent. I have basically followed this question's answer where he has duped2 stdout to the opened text file descriptor. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516823/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: If I duplicate my key and give it to you does that mean the door will magically open at that point? Of course not. After I duplicate the key you still need to do something with it. Same here. Duplicating a file descriptor does not magically cause data to be read or written. You still need to call functions that write to or read from those file descriptors. In this case, call any standard function to read from stdin (e.g. `scanf`, `fgets(.., stdin)`, etc) and write to `stdout` (e.g. `printf`, `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ..)`, etc). Give it a go by calling those functions in the child.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please provide more information on how to correctly read and
>   write in the child process?

If I duplicate my key and give it to you does that mean the door will magically open at that point? Of course not. After I duplicate the key you still need to do something with it. Same here. Duplicating a file descriptor does not magically cause data to be read or written. You still need to call functions that write to or read from those file descriptors. In this case, call any standard function to read from stdin (e.g. `scanf`, `fgets(.., stdin)`, etc) and write to `stdout` (e.g. `printf`, `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ..)`, etc). Give it a go by calling those functions in the child.
                    – kaylum